# Loop through an object's properties and update the values as empty string "" where property value is null

Tags: c#

I want to loop through all the properties of a POCO and wherever the property value is null. I want to set it to empty string. All the properties of the POCO is of type string.

Comment: And what did you try? Where are you stuck? SO is not a code-writing-service.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind from next time.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve it using [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection).

> Reflection provides objects (of type Type) that describe assemblies,
>   modules, and types. You can use reflection to dynamically create an
>   instance of a type, bind the type to an existing object, or get the
>   type from an existing object and invoke its methods or access its
>   fields and properties.

[`System.Reflection.PropertyInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo) discovers the attributes of a property and provides access to property metadata. You can retrieve all property info using [`Type.GetProperties()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties) method and work with values using [`GetValue(object)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties) and [`SetValue(object, value)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.setvalue).

```
var record = new YourClass();

PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(YourClass).GetProperties();

foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    if(property.PropertyType == typeof(string) && property.GetValue(record) == null)
        property.SetValue(record, string.Empty);
}
```